# Is is possible to use the value of a node property as a variable name for a relationship property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use the value of a node property as a variable name for a relationship property, and I haven't found any way to do it so far. Here is an example:

Let's say I have some node labels including:

```
(p:Person {id: #, name: "some name"})

(c:Currency {id: #, name: "currency symbol"})

(t:Transaction {id: #, amount: #}
```

In this case, the transaction is not linked to the currency, but ignore this for now. I want to create a relationship to show that some person transacted with another.

Assumptions:

1. c.name can be one of many currencies [USD, EUR, GBP, ... etc]
2. If person A sends multiple currencies to person B, then each currency will have its own transaction.

Now if p1 sent some amounts of USD and EUR to p2, I want to create a relationship as follows:

```
(p1:Person)-[TRANSACTED_WITH {USD: some amount, EUR: some amount}]->(p2:Person)
```

So I want the relationship to have the symbol name of a sent currency as the property name and the amount as the value of that property. There can be one or multiple currencies sent from A to B. So each relationship between two persons can have a different set of properties (depending on the sent currencies).

I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
MERGE (p1:Person)-[TRANSACTED_WITH {c1["name"]: t1.amount}]->(p2:Person)
```

Is there actually any way to do that?

Comment: cypher language cannot assign the property name c1["name"] to the relationship. You need to create a script like java or python to write the command string then execute that command.  show us the code that you are using and we can start from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [apoc.create.setRelProperties](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setRelProperties/) function like this:

```
MERGE (p1:Person {id: ...})-[T:TRANSACTED_WITH {id: ...}]->(p2:Person {id: ...})
CALL apoc.create.setRelProperties(T, [c1.name, c2.name], [amount1, amount2]) YIELD rel
```

Or just use one array to store keys and another to store values:

```
MERGE (p1:Person {id: ...})-[T:TRANSACTED_WITH {id: ...}]->(p2:Person {id: ...})
SET T.currencies = [c1.name, c2.name], T.amounts = [amount1, amount2]
```

But the best way in terms of graphs is to create an relation between a transaction with each currency from the transaction, each relation between a transaction and a currency has one value of the transaction amount.